# Outputting a string from a structure

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that takes input from a file, puts each word into a "words" structure, and then outputs the results with the frequency of each word, but whenever I try to output the string it just prints something like ?k@?? where I would expect the string to be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct s_words {
        char *str; //stores the word; no pre-determined size
       int count;
        struct s_words* next;
} words;

words* create_words(char* word) {
       //allocate space for the structure
        words* newWord = malloc(strlen(word));
        if (NULL != newWord){
            //allocate space for storing the new word in "str"
            //if str was array of fixed size, storage wud be wasted
            newWord->str = (char *)malloc(strlen(word));
            strcpy(newWord->str,word); //copy “word” into newWord->str
            newWord->str[strlen(word)]='\0';
            newWord->count = 1; //initialize count to 1;
            newWord->next = NULL; //initialize next;            
        }
        return newWord;
}

//If the word is in the list, add 1 to count. 
words* add_word(words* wordList, char* word) {
      int found=0;
        words *temp=wordList;
      // search if word exists in the list; if so, make found=1
      while (temp!=NULL) {
        //  printf("looptest\n");
        if (strcmp(word,temp->str) == 0) { //use strcmp command
            //printf("looptest0\n");
            found=1;
            temp->count = temp->count + 1; //increment count;
            return wordList;
           //printf("looptest1\n");
         }
         else {
            temp = temp -> next;  //update temp
           //  printf("looptest2\n");
        }
       }
     //   printf("looptest3\n");
      //new word
        words* newWord = create_words(word);
      //  printf("looptest4\n");
            if (NULL != newWord) {
              //   printf("looptest5\n");
                newWord->next = wordList;
                wordList = newWord;
                //Insert new word at the head of the list
            }
            else{
                // printf("looptest6\n");
                temp = wordList;
                while(temp->next != NULL){
                    // printf("looptest7\n");
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                temp->next = newWord;
            }
          return newWord;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    words *mywords;  //head of linked list containing words
        mywords=NULL;

    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen(argv[1],"r");  //first parameter is input file
        if (myFile==0) {
        printf("file not opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        printf("file opened\n");
    }

    //start reading file character by character;
    //when word has been detected; call the add_word function
    int ch, word = 0, k=0;
    char thisword[100];

        while ( (ch = fgetc(myFile)) != EOF )
        {
           // printf("%c",ch);
         if (ch==' ' || ch==',' || ch==';' || ch==':' || ch == '.')  //detect new word? Check if ch is a delimiter
         {
            // printf("\ncheck2\n");
            if ( word )  //make sure previous character was not delimiter
            {
               // printf("check\n");
               word = 0;
               thisword[k] = '\0'; //make the kth character of thisword as \0
              //  printf("test2\n");
               //now call add_word to add thisword into the list
               mywords = add_word(mywords,thisword);
              // printf("check3\n");
               k=0;
            }
            // printf("test\n");
         }
         else
         {
            word = 1;
             thisword[k] = ch; //make the kth character of thisword equal to ch
         k++;
         }
        if(ch == EOF){
            thisword[k] = '\0';
            mywords = add_word(mywords,thisword);
        }
      }

    printf("%s\n",mywords->str);
    printf("printing list\n");

    //Traverse list and print each word and its count to outputfile
    //output file is second parameter being passed
    //haven't started to deal with the output file
    words* temp = mywords;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%s\tcount: %i\n",temp->str,temp->count);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("list complete\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is all my code, I can't figure out how to error test what the problem is since I can't figure out how to output the strings. I've only started programming in C this year so I assume there's something basic I'm missing.

Comment: Failed to allocate space for the null terminator.

Comment: @MartinJames What does that mean? I added 1 to the malloc command in create_words but that did not change anything

Comment: I hope, for your sake, that no words are shorter than `sizeof(words)`, or else you will allocate to little memory for the structure in `create_words`.

Comment: Yoda conditions not useing you should. Since long time obsolete they are. Only complicating understanding the code they do.

Comment: **malloc()** statement is done wrongly, need to malloc enough for a full size string, only enough for a string pointer here.

Comment: @user3708770 - I did not intend to imply that it was your ONLY bug, just one of them:)

Comment: `words* newWord = malloc(strlen(word));` should be `words* newWord = malloc(sizeof(words));` because `newWord` will be pointing to `words` not `char`. `newWord->str = (char *)malloc(strlen(word));` lacks space for `null` terminator. You should try `newWord->str = strdup(word);`.  At the bottom of `add_words()`, don't you want to return `wordList` because that's the head of the list?

Comment: @alvits this helped a lot, thank you. I'm not sure which error fixed it but it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
    newWord->str = (char *)malloc(strlen(word));
    strcpy(newWord->str,word); //copy “word” into newWord->str
    newWord->str[strlen(word)]='\0';
```

.. writes the null out-of-bounds.

Assuming that strlen() returns the desired value, you should malloc an extra char:

```
    newWord->str = (char *)malloc(1+strlen(word));
```

Note Olaf comment re. casting in C.  Also note that it's unlikely that this is your ONLY bug.

Comment: @Olaf oh, thanks for pointing out my excessively-good copy/paste skills:)

Comment: Tried to add this, did not change anything

Comment: @user3708770 in the `create_words` function, what do you see if you print out `word`?

Comment: `malloc()` followed by `strcpy()` can be simplified with `strdup()`.

Comment: @user3708770 - There's no issue with `create_words()`. But in `add_words()` there is. The statement `return newWord` returns the node next to head. What happens when `newNode` is `NULL`? It will return `NULL`.

Comment: @alvits: `strdup` is not standard C. Not every implementations is POSIX-compliant.

Comment: @yano it prints nothing

Comment: @alvits it why is newWord the one next to head? Shouldn't it be the head? And shouldn't it never be null unless create_word is broken?

Comment: @user3708770 - `newWord` is `head` inside the `if (NULL != newWord)` block. What is the value of `newWord` in the else block? Of course `NULL`. `create_word()` can return`NULL` if `malloc()` failed to allocate memory. But I'm glad to hear that your issue is now resolved.